# Adding data-attributes in links override theme

Tags: theming

In the classy theme of drupal I would like to override this code

```html
{% if links -%}
  {%- if heading -%}
    {%- if heading.level -%}
      <{{ heading.level }}{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</{{ heading.level }}>
    {%- else -%}
      <h2{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</h2>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <ul{{ attributes }}>
    {%- for item in links -%}
      <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif %}
```

I would like to add `data-attribute` in the `<a>` tag output by {{ item.link }}.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to these usually is “in a preprocess function”.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how. There is no way to add an attribute directly on the link?